# How can put more parameters in ajaxFileUpload.... This is my ajaxfileupload code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile_pic/prof_photo_upload',
            secureuri: true,
            fileElementId: 'photoimg',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(resp){
                $('.right-register-container-left-rows-fields').html(resp);
            }
        });
```

Comment: which version of `ajaxFileUpload` are you using? please attach a url

Comment: I don't which version,In js file didn't mention which version..   I have attached the url        https://www.assembla.com/code/csdl_web/subversion/nodes/95/Source/js/ajaxfileupload.js

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object to the ajaxFileUpload, to add more parameters simply add a new properties to the object, for example:

```
jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile_pic/prof_photo_upload',
    type: "POST",
    secureuri: true,
    fileElementId: 'photoimg',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        somedata: "XXX",
        moredata: "YYY"
    },
    success: function(resp) {
        $('.right-register-container-left-rows-fields').html(resp);
    }
});
```